# Flutter cannot run in debug mode on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

When running a flutter project, it can no longer be **run in debug mode**. I get this error message (debug console):

```
SocketException: Failed to create datagram socket (OS Error: Address already in use, errno = 48), address = , port = 5353
```

The app starts and then gets stuck on the launching screen. When later clicking play in Xcode, the app launches (not connected to the debugger however).
Does anyone have similar issues? I believe the issue is related to the new Xcode Version 15.0.1.  [Related thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/134667)

iOS: 17.1.2, iPhone 13
Xcode: 15.0.1
Flutter: Stable, 3.16.3